# Deactivate a function in Azure Logic App Workflow using the designer

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am stuck with a problem that initially seems quite trivial. The thing is, I need to deactivate a Function in an Azure Resource Group, but I can only do it using the Designer, and I don't have access to the Active Directory. Apparently, it's something straightforward, but I can't find which Action I can use to Disable or Enable the Function. Here's a screenshot of the Designer that currently works perfectly.

[image]

Does anyone know which Action I should use to Disable or Enable another function in this scenario?

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: Do you mean stopping the function app in a resource group ?

Comment: Yes. I just want to to this. So, Which is the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTTP connector by calling the below Azure Management REST API's you can meet your requirement.

1. [STOP webapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/stop) REST API --> To start/stop the function app.
2. [WebApp- Update Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/update-application-settings)--> To enable or disable a particular function inside a function app.

For example, If you have Queue trigger function in your function app and you want to disable then you need to update the application setting `AzureWebJobs.QueueTrigger.Disabled`

Similarly, each function you will have a specific [application setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=powershell) related to it based on the trigger.

For more information, refer to this [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/azure-rest-api-through-logic-app/ba-p/2193956) on how to call Azure Management REST API through logic app.

**Updated Answer:**

To test this, we have enabled managed identity to logic App, assigned contributor role to that managed identity and we are able to stop the function app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the first option, I get a 500 error. Maybe I need permissions to Active Directory? And in the case of the second option... there is an HTTP PUT, what should I pass? Sorry I'm confused but I know that's the correct way.

Comment: @MadDev If you are using Managed identity then you need to assign the contributor permission on that function or you can assign the contributor role at resource group and check. Also please refer to the updated answer.